# UserControl Dependencyproperty not updating through binding

Tags: binding, user-controls, windows-8, mvvm-light, dependency-properties

I'm creating a Windows 8 app, and I'm struggling the last couple of days with a custom user control. I can't really figure out whats wrong.

The weird thing is that the dependencyproperty calls the propertychanged event when I change Source in code, but with the binding its not updating.

So here's my code:

GamePage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class GamePage
    {
        GamePageViewModel viewModel;

        public GamePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new GamePageViewModel();
        }
    }
```

GamePage.xaml

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage x:Class="WordSearcher.GamePage"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:common="using:WordSearcher.Common"
                        xmlns:controls="using:WordSearcher.Controls"
                        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
                        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
                        d:DesignHeight="768"
                        d:DesignWidth="1366"
                        DataContext="{Binding GamePageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Wood.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </StackPanel.Background>
<controls:PuzzleControl Source="{Binding Path=PuzzleData}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

GamePageViewModel.cs

```
public class GamePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<string> _puzzleData;

        public List<string> PuzzleData
        {
            get
            {
                return _puzzleData;
            }
            set
            {
                this._puzzleData = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PuzzleData");
            }
        }

        public GamePageViewModel()
        {
            SetNewData();
        }

        private async void SetNewData()
        {
            await SomeManager.Prepare();
            PuzzleData = SomeManager.Create(20);
        }
    }
```

PuzzleControl.xaml.cs

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WordSearcher.Controls.PuzzleControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WordSearcher.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="500"
    d:DesignWidth="500">

    <Grid x:Name="puzzleGrid" 
          Width="500" 
          Height="500"
          >

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

PuzzleControl.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class PuzzleControl : UserControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(PuzzleControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChanged));

        private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // not called from binding
            //
            ((PuzzleControl)d).OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(e);
        }

        private void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Source = (ObservableCollection<string>)e.NewValue;
            SetGridData();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Source
        {
            get
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(SourceProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public PuzzleControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            CreateRowsAndColumns();
        }

        private void CreateRowsAndColumns()
        {
            //create rows and columns in puzzleGrid
            //works fine
        }

        private void SetGridData()
        {
            //fill puzzleGrid with data
            //works fine
        }
    }
```

Does anyone knows with is wrong in my code? Because when I put Source = new ObservableCollection(); in the constructor of PuzzleData, the PropertyChanged event will raise. Is it anything with the DataContext?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure,

but you set `<controls:PuzzleControl Source="{Binding Path=PuzzleData}"/>`

```
PuzzleData = List<string>
```

and

```
Source = ObservableCollection<string>
```

If the binding even works the first time (what it apperantly does) then it might be the case the source is set to List`<string>` in some way instead of `ObservableCollection<string>`. That might be the case why your dependencyproperty method (`PropertyChanged`) is not called because it is registered to `ObservableCollection<string>`.

But this is all pure speculation, haven't tested it.

---

After I got his code an reviewed it I found out that the PuzzleData was never really set and that that was the error... False Alarm....

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure binding context? And How binding object? If you use your user control like in a gridview, DataContext is changed, and differend Datacontext of root page.

```
<controls:PuzzleControl Source="{Binding Path=DataContext.PuzzleData}"/>
```

if you use sub control, your  user control; bind ElementName property like this:

```
<controls:PuzzleControl Source="{Binding Path=DataContext.PuzzleData, ElementName=pageRoot}"/>
```

If you not sure, tracing DataContext binding values on debug via breakpoints.